# query ajax запрос - как решить проблему? В чем проблема 2-го цикла

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, комментарии

Вот код, html ->

```
    <div class="all-content"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вот мой js ->

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '****',
    type: 'GET',
    dateType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log("Count of data items: ", data.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // console.log( data[i].children.created_at);
            let $block = $(`
        <div class="container" id="comments-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 offset-lg-1">
                <div class="profile-photo">
                    <img class="profile-img"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <div class="pname text-muted"></div>

              <div class="pdate text-muted"></div>
              <br>
              <div class="content"></div>
              <div class="all-simple-content"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
`);

            $block.find(".pname").text(data[i].author.name);
            $block.find(".profile-img").attr('src', data[i].author.avatar);
            $block.find(".pdate").text(data[i].author.created_at);
            $block.find(".content").text(data[i].content);
            $(".all-content").append($block);

            for (let n = 0; n < data[i].children.length; n++) {
                let $simpleBlock = $(`
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1 offset-lg-2">
                <img class="profile-img-children" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="pname-children text-muted"></div>

                <div class="pdate-children text-muted"></div>
                <br>
                <div class="content-children"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
`);
                if (data[i].children[n] == undefined) {
                    return false;
                }

                $simpleBlock.find(".content-children").text(data[i].children[n].content);
                $simpleBlock.find(".pdate-children").text( data[i].children[n].created_at );
                $simpleBlock.find(".profile-img-children").attr('src', data[i].children[n].author.avatar);
                $simpleBlock.find(".pname-children").text(data[i].children[n].author.name);
                $(".all-simple-content").append($simpleBlock);
                console.log(data[i]);
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        _method: 'GET'
    }
});
```

Вот что выходит далее ->

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду, точнее

Comment: убрать len = data.length

Comment: И что это поменяет?

Comment: в чем проблема то ? у вас верстка нарисована на  один основной и один дочерний коммент. Если вопрос в том- нужен ли вложенный цикл для генерации всей цепочки вложенных - да нужен.

Comment: Я и хочу узнать - как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DmitryKozlov прав. Переменная `len`, несмотря на две декларации, существует в одном экземпляре. Уберите ее. Кроме того, во втором цикле неправильный верхний предел счетчика:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  ...
  for (var n = 0; n < data[i].children.length; n++) {
    ...
```

Еще не ясен смысл двух `return;` в конце обработчика `success`. Их тоже надо убрать.

*Update*

И вместо

```
$(".all-simple-content").append($simpleBlock);
```

используйте

```
$block.find(".all-simple-content").append($simpleBlock);
```

чтобы вставить новый `$simpleBlock` в текущий `$block`.

Comment: Это не решает основной проблемы кода, скорее всего у меня в синтаксисе кода есть какая то ошибка, потому что верхний цикл не перезапускается все равно.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Что, в данном случае, означает слово "перезапускается"? Вы выходите из функции после первой итерации внешнего цикла - первым `return`-ом.

Comment: Немного помогло, но в отредактированном вопросе, сейчас покажу в чем проблема

Comment: То есть, у меня откуда-то взялся 4 children, а для остальных data[i] вообще не получаю нужные данные